# C# Error de Conexion MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy realizando un proyecto en C# pero cuando intento realizar la conexion a la base de datos no abre y Genera el Siguiente error

[image: Conexion mediante la Ip de mi maquina local]

[image: Mediante localhost y genera el mismo error el ambas pares]

este es mi codigo

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("Server=10.0.0.9; Port=3308; Database= baseprincipal; Uid=root; Pwd=; ");
            conexion.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show( this,ex.Message,"error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: revisa conectividad de red y firewall

Comment: Tengo acceso a internet y el firewall de windows esta desactivado

Comment: En la configuración de mysql mira los permisos para conexiones remotas para el usuario root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale permisos al usuario para que se pueda conectar remotamente;

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
>   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;